# Customizing fileTemplate option on FineUploader

Tags: jquery, html, css, fine-uploader

First, I want to say that my English is not good, so I want to make apologies. My problem is that I am trying to customize FineUploader FileTemplate option without success.
I don´t want to use fineUploaderBasic. I want to have total customization. First of all I was trying to hide file name and size after the upload was success and I succesfully do it, but when I try to customize the delete button the problem begins. After the upload the delete button appears but disabled, I can not click it. Below Is my code:

```
var restricteduploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                        element: $('#restricted-fine-uploader')[0],
                        text: {
                            uploadButton: '<div><i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>Subir Imagen</div>',
                            deleteButton: '<input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Eliminar imagen" />'
                        },

                        template:
                        '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
                            '<div class="qq-upload-drop-area"><span>{dragZoneText}</span></div>' +
                            '<div class="qq-upload-button">{uploadButtonText}</div>' +
                            '<span class="qq-drop-processing"><span>{dropProcessingText}</span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
                            '<ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' +
                        '</div>',
                        fileTemplate:
                            '<li>' +
                                '<div class="qq-progress-bar"></div>' +
                                '<span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span>' +
                                '<span class="qq-upload-finished"></span>' +
                                '<span class="qq-edit-filename-icon"></span>' +
                                '<span class="hide-file"></span>' +
                                '<div>IMAGEN SUBIDA CON EXITO!!</div>' +
                                '<input class="qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">' +
                                '<span class="hide-size"></span>' +
                                '<a class="qq-upload-cancel" href="#">{cancelButtonText}</a>' +
                                '<a class="qq-upload-retry" href="#">{retryButtonText}</a>' +
                                '<div class="qq-upload-delete">{deleteButtonText}</div>' +
                                '<span class="qq-upload-status-text">{statusText}</span>' +
                            '</li>',
                        classes: {
                            file: 'hide-file',
                            size: 'hide-size'
                        },
                        request: {
                            endpoint: '<%= Url.Action("UploadBatchDataFile", "Account") %>'
                        },
                        deleteFile: {
                            enabled: true,
                            endpoint: '<%= Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Account") %>',
                            method: 'POST'
                        },
                        multiple: false,
                        validation: {
                            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
                            sizeLimit: 411062 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
                        },
                        showMessage: function (message) {
                            $('#restricted-fine-uploader').append('<div class="alert-error">' + message + '</div>');
                        },
                        //listElement: document.getElementById('files'),
                        messages: { typeError : "{file} no es un tipo de imagen valido. Imagenes valida(s): {extensions}." },
                        callbacks: {
                            onSubmitDelete: function(event, id) {
                                var filename = $(this).fineUploader('getName', id);
                                $(this).fineUploader('setDeleteFileParams', {filename: filename}, id);
                            },
                            onComplete: function (id, filename, responseJSON) {
                                if (responseJSON.success) {
                                    $('div div.alert-error').remove();

                                    $('#imgUploaded').attr("src", "<%: Url.Content("~/Images/") %>" + responseJSON.filename);
                                    $('#hidImage').attr("value", "<%: Url.Content("~/Images/") %>" + responseJSON.filename);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

For me it's very difficult to customize the fileTemplate, before this I was trying to make the FileTemplate a part of a table, changing this on template

```
'<ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' to '<table class="qq-upload-list"></table>'
```

and this on fileTemplate

```
'<li>' to '<tr><td>' and '</li>' to </td></tr>
```

But again this doesn´t work, after a succesfully upload FineUploader doesn´t shows me the FileTemplate.

Comment: Please don't replace incorrect code in your question based on advice from answers.  This makes it very difficult for future readers to determine what you are asking.  I have rolled back your last edit.  If you have questions about the code suggested in the answer, include your questions as a comment on the associated answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, inside of your `onComplete` handler change you have a syntax error. Change

```
$('#imgUploaded').attr("src", "<%: Url.Content("~/Images/") %>" + responseJSON.filename);
$('#hidImage').attr("value", "<%: Url.Content("~/Images/") %>" + responseJSON.filename);
```

to

```
$('#imgUploaded').attr("src", "<%: Url.Content('~/Images/') %>" + responseJSON.filename);
$('#hidImage').attr("value", "<%: Url.Content('~/Images/') %>" + responseJSON.filename);
```

Secondly, in your [`text` option properties](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/options/fineuploader.html#text-option-properties) you are providing HTML rather than the string of text you want to appear inside of the button. So you should change,

```
text: {
    uploadButton: '<div><i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>Subir Imagen</div>',
    deleteButton: '<input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Eliminar imagen" />'
},
```

to

```
text: {
    uploadButton: 'Subir Imagen',
    deleteButton: 'Eliminar imagen'
},
```

If you would still like to add an upload icon (as I see you did), or customize the HTML in any other way, then modify the [`template` option properties](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/styling.html):

```
template:
    '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
        '<div class="qq-upload-drop-area"><span>{dragZoneText}</span></div>' +
        '<div class="qq-upload-button"><i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>{uploadButtonText}</div>' +
        '<span class="qq-drop-processing"><span>{dropProcessingText}</span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
        '<ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' +
        '</div>',
```

Lastly, you appear to have a mixture of jQuery and non-jQuery code within your instance of FineUploader. You know [there's a jQuery plugin for FineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/#jquery-wrapper-demo), right? It'd make your life a lot easier, and it'd make your callbacks actually work because the value of `this` in

```
onSubmitDelete: function(event, id) {
    var filename = $(this).fineUploader('getName', id);
    $(this).fineUploader('setDeleteFileParams', {filename: filename}, id);
},
```

is simply not going to be the element that FineUploader is instantiated on. If you were using the jQuery plugin, then that would work.

With the jQuery plugin you can just do ...

```
$("#restricted-fine-uploader").fineUploader({
    // .. define your options here, same as above ...
}).on('submitDelete', function (event, id) {
    var filename = $(this).fineUploader('getName', id);
    $(this).fineUploader('setDeleteFileParams', {filename: filename}, id);

}).on('complete', function (event, id, filename, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success) {
        $('div div.alert-error').remove();

        $('#imgUploaded').attr("src", "<%: Url.Content('~/Images/') %>" + responseJSON.filename);
        $('#hidImage').attr("value", "<%: Url.Content('~/Images/') %>" + responseJSON.filename);

    }
});
```

[Here is a link to documentation on how to use the jQuery plugin](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/modes/using-jquery-plugin.html)

## Update

Here is some more code showing exactly how to a) use the jQuery plugin and events properly and b) how to use an `input` element for one's delete button.

**note:** this requires FineUploader >=3.7.1

### JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $("#restricted-fine-uploader").fineUploader({
        text: {
            uploadButton: "<i class='icon-upload icon-white'></i>Subir Imagen"
        },
        fileTemplate:
            '<li>' +
            '<div class="qq-progress-bar"></div>' +
            '<span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span>' +
            '<span class="qq-upload-finished"></span>' +
            '<span class="hide-file"></span>' +
            '<div>IMAGEN SUBIDA CON EXITO!!</div>' +
            '<span class="hide-size"></span>' +
            '<a class="qq-upload-cancel" href="#">{cancelButtonText}</a>' +
            '<a class="qq-upload-retry" href="#">{retryButtonText}</a>' +
            '<input class="qq-upload-delete" type="button" value="{deleteButtonText}" />' +
            '<span class="qq-upload-status-text">{statusText}</span>' +
            '</li>',

        classes: {
            file: 'hide-file',
            size: 'hide-size'
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: '<%= Url.Action("UploadBatchDataFile", "Account") %>'
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,
            endpoint: '<%= Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Account") %>',
            method: 'POST'
        },
        multiple: false,
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
            sizeLimit: 411062 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
        },
        showMessage: function (message) {
            $('#restricted-fine-uploader').append('<div class="alert-error">' + message + '</div>');
        },
        //listElement: document.getElementById('files'),
        messages: {
            typeError: "{file} no es un tipo de imagen valido. Imagenes valida(s): {extensions}."
        }
    }).on('submitDelete', function (event, id) {
        var filename = $(this).fineUploader('getName', id);
        $(this).fineUploader('setDeleteFileParams', {
            filename: filename
        }, id);
    }).on('complete', function (id, filename, responseJSON) {
        if (responseJSON.success) {
            $('div div.alert-error').remove();

            $('#imgUploaded').attr('src', '<%: Url.Content("~/Images/") %>' + responseJSON.filename);
            $('#hidImage').attr('value', '<%: Url.Content("~/Images/") %>' + responseJSON.filename);

        }
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<ul id="restricted-fine-uploader"></ul>
```

Comment: I modify the code us you suggests, but your answer doesn´t solve my problem. I edit the post, because the code is not corresponding with the question.

Comment: The code I provided you works, and is thoroughly tested. Your updated code is incorrect. First off, you are using qq.FineUploader, but adding event listeners via the jQuery plugin method. Secondly, there is no need for you to specify any `template` options because they are the exact same as the default. Thirdly, your function signatures for your event handlers are completely wrong. I highly doubt your code even evaluates correctly in any browser.

Comment: Ray Nicholus, you are right I am a new user and I don't know how to add correction to my post based on the answer of mfeltner, without modify the original code.                                                mfeltner I do all as you suggest. The code works for uploads, I tested on my WebSite, for sure I need to modify the part where the delete is handled "submitDelete, etc", but if I change the link that handles the delete for and Input button, the Input is disabled. Again I can't change the fileTemplate

Comment: @Pato , could you clarify exactly what you mean by: "change the link that handles the delete for and Input button, the Input is disabled. Again I can't change the fileTemplate"?

Comment: Ok, on the fileTemplate option, I modify this <a class="qq-upload-delete" href="#">{deleteButtonText}</a> for '<input class="qq-upload-delete" type="button" value="{deleteButtonText}" />'. After a succesfull Upload the fileTemplate appears but the input is disabled. I can't click it, If I leave the link when I click it the action is called. I am programming MVC. What I am trying to do is to understand how the fineUploader works, I want to be able to change all its options, I'm evaluating to buying it, but I need to know all the features and how to change use its.

Comment: mfeltner, my project design is the same as you with little differences that the one you posted on the update. Anyway I have copied your code and pasted in my project. And again when the upload is successfull and the fileTemplate comes, it doesn´t show and enabled input button. I can't click it. Tell me if you need more about the solution, the action of the controller I don´t know what to do or what to show to you.

Comment: Is this issue specific to a certain browser?

Comment: I tested on Internet Explorer 8 and works horrible, before the action returns JSon with its parameters a PopUp modal appears asking where I want to save a file. The files contains in plain text the JSon response. I suppose, I need to add something on the request option. Before I was working on Chrome Versión 28.0.1500.72m, I installed fiddler to know why the JSon result comes empty, this happens after the updates on the code. Looking in fiddler the JSon response is correctly, I don´t understand why the complete callback cannot has the Json response correct. Maybe this has something to do.

Comment: I have modified the function of the complete event "function (id, filename, responseJSON)" to "function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON)" and now I get the responseJson correct, the definition was missing one parameter "event". But the button is still disabled. In Internet Explorer 8 I has the same problem that I comment before even if a change CustomHeader accept.

Comment: mfeltner, I have seeing the jsfiddle, but it doesn´t help me, because I can´t upload a picture therefore I can´t see the fileTemplate. Just to comment.

Comment: @Pato, I'm sorry this is not working for you. The code works for me in all supported browsers. :( Two more ideas: What version of FineUploader are you using? Are you planning to use the "Edit Filename" feature? I would suggest upgrading to the latest version, and -- if you are not using that feature -- remove any elements with a class starting with "qq-edit-*" from your `fileTemplate`.

Comment: mfeltner, Thank You! for your support, I removed all the element from the fileTemplate with class "qq-edit-*", the button is now enabled, I can click it and the action for delete is called. When I come home after my Work I will test on IE 8 and I let you know this problem of the file with JSon return still remains. I am using version 3.7.0, In the future is going to be a version with support to my Chrome version and IE8 for not to make this trick of remove those elements? and enable the edit file feature?. How can I post the updated code for users how may need it?. Again thank you!

Comment: @Pato, no problemo it's mah job ;) -- I would suggest implementing your changes. If you have a separate question related to FineUploader, post a new one here on StackOverflow and one of the maintainers will get to you. I also wanted to add that if you want edit filename to work you are going to need to get the 3.7.1 release of FineUploader. A hotfix was released in that version which fixes a bug related to the edit filename feature and delete/cancel button.

If my suggestions worked for you, then an accepted answer and/or upvote would be fantastic! :D

Comment: mfeltner, ok I have downloaded the latest version and now I can enable the edition of files in my Chrome version. I will open a new post if I can't resolve IE8 upload problem. thank you very much!